# node.js twitter bot using twit.stream and twit.post

Tags: node.js, twitter, bots, raspberry-pi3

Forgive me if this sounds like a numbskull question - I am not an expert at these things. I have a couple twitter bots running on a Raspberry Pi 3. Both use Twit (https://www.npmjs.com/package/twit). One just posts and one uses the stream API. They are both running out of the same directory, but they seem to be interfering with each other. The RPi crashes and I have to power cycle the thing. If this question is incomprehensible without seeing the code, I will upload it to github or somewhere. The question is: Is there a trick to using T.post(...) and T.stream(...) in the same bot?

Comment: this isn't enough to go on, can you give us some example code? could be a simplified version if you don't want to give out too much proprietary info